# Error integrando django con react

Tags: python, django, reactjs

Estoy integrando react en django y me arroja este error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi archivo de webpack-stats.json después de hacer el webpack me queda de la siguiente manera.

```
{"status":"done","chunks":{"main":["main-6c83efdba2d1c8682cba.js"]},"assets":{"main-6c83efdba2d1c8682cba.js":{"name":"main-6c83efdba2d1c8682cba.js","path":"D:\\Python\\Python\\ProjectsWeb\\biblioteca\\backend\\assets\\bundles\\main-6c83efdba2d1c8682cba.js"}}}
```

Al parecer es un error de los índices, en mi archivo index invoco a mi componente con `{% render_bundle "main" %}`

**Edit:** Agrego el código de mi proyecto en github
https://github.com/bsjaramillo/Python/tree/master/ProjectsWeb/biblioteca/backend

Comment: Hola! Podrías incluir en la publicación el código que utilizaste, así podemos ver que hiciste?

Comment: @vschiaffino yap, agregue el código en github.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné bajando la versión del webpack loader, las nuevas versiones generar una configuración en el webpack-stats.json, por lo cuál no podía encontrar el nombre especificado en el render_bundle "main"
Usé esta versión:npm install --save-dev webpack-bundle-tracker@0.4.3